# Weird Java Exception name

Tags: java, exception

I did a System.out.print with a object that was null and I got this:

```
550270261027054028026002805302902590290520300258030051031025703105003202560320
490330255033048034025403404703502530350460360252036045037025103704403802500380
43039024903904204002480Exception
```

I tried googling it but the name of the exception was too long.

Does anyone know what this exception means?

```
for (int i = bulletList.size(); i > 0; i--) {
        final Bullet b = bulletList.get(i - 1);/* the bullet is just a class containing it's image, its position and its rectangle and handling its movement*/
        b.r = new Rectangle(b.x, b.y, 34, 20);
        for (i = obsticalList.size(); i > 0; i--) {
            final Obstical o = obsticalList.get(i - 1);//Obsical class is like the bullet class but for stationary thing
            System.out.print(o.r.x);
            System.out.print(b.r.x);//This is where I get the exception
        }

    }



3202452730245310255272025530026527102652902752700Exception in thread "Thread-3"
    at StartingClass.checkCollision(StartingClass.java:175)
    at StartingClass.run(StartingClass.java:107)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Can you post your code and the complete stack trace please?

Comment: Generally that means you did a System.out.print on a null.

Comment: Post that **awesome** code snippet, which gave this **marvelous** `Exception`.

Comment: You are reusing the loop counter `i` in the inner loop. Is that intentional? Your outer loop will never "loop" because of this.

Comment: @erickson It's possible that the reuse is eventually causing `obsticalList.get(i - 1)` to throw something.

Comment: @michaelb958 The first encounter with the inner loop sets `i` to the size of `obsticalList`, then counts down to zero. Then then loop condition of the outer loop is checked again; since `i` is now zero, the outer loop terminates.

Comment: @erickson Oops. Don't mind me, I obviously can't read code that well :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The digits aren't part of the exception name. Your code is printing digits with no line feeds to standard out.

The default exception handler prints a stack trace to standard error. Messages from standard output and standard error are being interleaved on your console, so the digits you see are from your code, and the "Exception" is fragment of the stack trace.

Most likely, if you look back further in the console, you'll see the beginning of the exception name. The only runtime exception the line you indicate could throw is a `NullPointerException`, if `b` or `b.r` is null; but, given your code, it doesn't look like that is possible. Maybe the exception is really thrown from another line. Line numbers and a stack trace would help pin this down, but perhaps it's a `NullPointerException` from the previous line.

Answer (score 1):

System.out.print(obj) with obj = null will simply print word `null`.